# Translation of "sharing key"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am a native speaker, but I have no idea how to translate "sharing key" into German.
I don't know if there are multiple meanings of "sharing key", but just in case, I am talking about a string that is to be typed in an application to be able to connect with another application for sharing files etc.

Does anyone have an idea? Just "Schlüssel" was the best I could find, but it is not specialized enough in some contexts.

Comment: Sharing Key habe ich so noch nie gehört. Sind wir hier in der Kryptografie und sprechen [hiervon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key).

Comment: Es geht um die Übersetzung einer Smartphone App (http://superbe.am/), bei der eine Zeichenkette eingegeben werden kann, um das versenden von Dateien zu autorisieren. Ich habe die englische Version nicht geschrieben, deshalb weiß ich nicht, ob es vielleicht eine neuerfindung des Programmierers ist.

Comment: Ok. Also ich plädiere für "verteilter Schlüssel", da der Schlüssel eben im vorhinein an alle Nutzer *verteilt* wird (sharing halt). Wäre der "offizielle" Begriff.

Comment: OK danke, ich schau morgen mal, ob sich das in den Sätzen vernünftig anhört.

Comment: Wie ich die Frage verstanden habe, ist es ein Schlüssel fürs Teilen, kein ver-/geteilter Schlüssel (shared key). Ein guter Begriff fällt mir nicht ein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing i can think of that wouldn't feel wrong to native germans is `Freigabeschlüssel`.